# copying visual studio project to new location

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

I have a small visual studio project that is in my personal directory. I know need to copy this project to my team directory but am having issues with the solution file.

I have been following this [example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/697108/Visual-Studio-Painlessly-Renaming-Your-Project-and). All is fine until I get near to the bottom of the page at the section Editing the Solution File. When I open my solution file in notepad++ most of it is NUL or other unreadable symbols. I can see a few lines of english which is the directory location. However doing a ctrl find of "Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File" does not find anything or even the word "Project".

I have tried updating the directory location to the new location in this file but the solution does not load in Visual Studio. It just seems to me my solution file is pretty different to the one in the example?

Comment: Your solution file appears to be corrupt. It should be a text file.

Comment: just looked at two other project solutions (nothing to do with the project mentioned above) they also appear corrupt. The code runs fine though

Comment: I would create a new, empty solution, then use "Add Existing Project" to add the projects.

Comment: Yes that's done it. Strange though! Thanks

Comment: Does the new solution look anything like the old solution?

Comment: No looked very different. Its my first day back in the office. Speaking to our IT team it appears my Visual Studio was updated over the weekend. Can only think that must have done something